# Is there a tool that will create Java or .NET classes from a db4o database file?

Tags: db4o

I have a db4o database file. Is there a tool that will generate Java or .NET classes (source) from this database?

Comment: Afaik no. But I going to write one in the next few weeks for a little pet project of mine for .NET

Comment: I'd be interested in looking at that if you decide to release it.

Comment: Ok, I'll notify you when I've got a working prototype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None that I'am aware of.

But it should not be to hard to write one. You can use ObjectContainer.Ext().KnownClasses() method.